# Two differente validations for one Model in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Transfer model in my Rails 5 app.
In my controller I have a create and a quotation method. My challenge is now that I want to apply differente validations for each method.

When I create a new Transfer I want to validate the entire object. But in my quotation method I want to apply just some of the validations. For example to create a Transfer I need to validate the passengers, but to return the quotation there are no passengers needed.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `before_action` callbacks to validate each action?

```
class Transfer < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :passengers_present
  before_action :quotation_valdiation, only: :quotation
  ...

  private

  def passengers_present
    errors.add("must have passengers") unless passengers.count > 0
  end

  def quotation_validation
    errors.add("failure message") if failure
  end
end
```